# What privileges for custom settings access to users?

Tags: customsetting

I've a complex mobile app which we've generalised using custom settings. There are certain fields that I want to make available to users who're not system admins. Is there a way I can do that without making them giving admin privileges?

Are there any specific permissions which control a user's access to custom settings?

Answer (score 1):

If I get your question correctly, you want to control the access based on user, you can go for Hierarchy Custom Settings

> A type of custom setting that uses a built-in hierarchical logic that
>   lets you “personalize” settings for specific profiles or users. The
>   hierarchy logic checks the organization, profile, and user settings
>   for the current user and returns the most specific, or “lowest,”
>   value. In the hierarchy, settings for an organization are overridden
>   by profile settings, which, in turn, are overridden by user settings.

Hierarchy custom settings can be configured at varying user levels

- User
- Profile
- Org

Comment: Hi Bennie, thank you for the answer. That is not what I want however. I want to be able to expose custom settings only to certain users.

Comment: @user10740 Unfortunately, there's no other way, you have to grant the permission set 'Customize Application' to these users. You can't hide one or two custom settings or specific fields on custom settings like you do for a sObject.

Comment: For what it's worth, users without admin privileges can't update those settings at all. Only code running as them can update the setting values.